# Do sports drinks make a difference in a workout?

Tags: nutrition, workout

Both [Gatorade](http://www.gatorade.com/default.aspx#home) and [Powerade](http://www.powerade.com/) claim to help fill your bodies needs of electrolytes, vitamins, and other nutrients.  I'm looking to find out if there's documented proof that these drinks really make a difference in your workout or replenishment of nutrients.

Comment: Tim Ferriss reports that some experiments have showed that simply rinsing your mouth with a sweet tasting - but calory empty - solution will result in some performance improvement.  Interesting, huh?

Comment: @JDelage do you have a reference, or link or study to back that up?

Comment: http://digitalcommons.wku.edu/ijesab/vol2/iss3/6/

Comment: @JDelage I'm agree with Tim Ferries, because I have seen a episode on Discovery channel, who said the same and also carried out a experiment on two group of people, and group "that simply rinsing your mouth with a sweet tasting - but calory empty - solution" performed better than other group who actually drunk that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The effectiveness of commercially available sports drinks.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10739268)

This study from the University of Tasmania suggests so:

> Our conclusions are 3-fold.
>
> - First, because of variations in drink composition and research design, much of the sports drinks research from the past cannot be applied directly to the effectiveness of currently available sports drinks.
> - Secondly, in studies where a practical protocol has been used along with a currently available sports beverage, there is evidence to suggest that consuming a sports drinks will improve performance compared with consuming a placebo beverage.
> - Finally, there is little evidence that any one sports drink is superior to any of the other beverages on the market.

Comment: "there is evidence to suggest that consuming a sports drink **will improve performance** compared with consuming a placebo beverage" suggests that sports drinks do help improve performance.

Comment: duly modified...